# Linux kernel bottom half priority VS kthread priority

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a kernel module that has one running kthread and one threaded IRQ whose bottom half is implemented neither as work queue nor as tasklet; I'm just doing all the processing I need directly in it. Both Kthread and bottom half have to access SPI bus so a mutex protection is used to protect the bus access.

The problem I'm facing here is that kthread is kept blocked on the mutex to be released although bottom half process keeps locking and unlocking the mutex several times for a pretty long time. It seems like that bottom half process has a much higher priority than my kthread. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: It's essential that soft IRQ has higher priority then a kernel thread, because it's an IRQ. What help do you need?

Comment: another problem would be when your heavy, low priority process will capture the mutex and will be switched, blocking software IRQ. In another words you have design problem that can't be solved without detailed information.

Comment: Threaded IRQ is also a kernel thread. I'm not sure what you are asking here exactly. They both have same level of priority.

Comment: @nopasara As far as I know, bottom half (soft IRQ) can be blocked as it's a normal process, so I don't know why there is a design problem.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko My information is that you can implement bottom half as kernel thread or work queue or neither. So do you mean that bottom half function is a kernel thread by default?

Comment: **Threaded IRQ** assumes kernel thread for bottom half. It can't be **neither** as you put in your question. If there is a bottom half it should be either kernel thread, or work queue, or tasklet, or any other form of deferred task.

Comment: I never mentioned they can't be interrupted. But it's still an interrupt handler. I'll post you a quote "But when is "later"? The important thing to realize is that later is often simply not now. The point of a bottom half is not to do work at some specific point in the future, but simply to defer work until any point in the future when the system is less busy and interrupts are again enabled. Often, bottom halves run immediately after the interrupt returns. The key is that they run with all interrupts enabled." from [here](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch07lev1sec1)